# Why is using f.length() in a for loop so inefficient in java?

Tags: java, file, for-loop

I was writing a program that uses some file processing using the file class and a Buffered Input and Output Streams and found that when I used the following code

```
for(long j = 0; j < f2.length(); j++) {
    out.write(in.read());
}
```

was highly inefficient, taking about 15251 milliseconds. However if I saved f2.length() to a variable first

```
long y = f2.length();
for(long j = 0; j < y; j++) {
    out.write(in.read());
}
```

it only takes 74 milliseconds. Why is the second block so much more efficient?

Comment: how did u measure?

Comment: Storing System.currentTimeMillis() when starting the method it was in and subtracting that from System.currentTimeMillis() after the method was completed.

Comment: that is a very bad way, there are dedicated libraries for such micro testing, like `JMH`. Because you measured with a pretty wrong way, these numbers are irrelevant.

Comment: A guess : there are some I/O each time you call `f2.length()` and that is costly

Comment: Is `f2` a `File`? Because yes, that could be a costly operation

Comment: Yes, but the idea was more a rough comparison to demonstrate how much slower the first way was, and I don't know why.

Comment: And yes, it is a file

Comment: If you did those two measurements say one after the other (and say the streams [right?]) are referring to files that haven't been loaded before, then the second (saved) version might be heaps faster because the file came from a cache in memory...

Comment: It did not matter what order I did them in, the one was always far slower than the other, and I am not running them in the same program. I ran it once, changed the code, then ran it again.

Comment: Of course if you are reading from a file/stream to make a copy, you should rely on what the stream says about remaining elements, not make a call to get size which in the mean time could change...  The reader/inputstream knows what it has left to go (well when it will run out).

Comment: I would also do this `final long y = f2.length();` - just so you don't mistakenly  change your calculated size ... [not an issue with tens of lines of code, but when you have 10 or 100K you have to protect against the humans].

Comment: 206 times faster....was the file located in a usb 1.0 or similar? because that's a lot..

Comment: No, the file was off an internal SSD, which is why I am especially confused. The code above is used in a program, but other than those two lines it is exactly the same code, so it should not make much difference with the numbers.

Comment: just for curiosity, could you provide the core test code?

Comment: I can't in this case, but the program breaks a file (in this case a pdf) into 0.25 megabyte parts, and then reassembles them into the pdf again. The original file is 607Kb, as is the output file.

Comment: you do have a point here, I'm having similar results

Comment: If you care for performance, don’t read a file byte by byte. But even if you do, `read()` will return `-1` when reaching the end of the file. Just check for that, without polling `length()` all the time. So this is another [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). You should have asked “how do I split files efficiently” instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that saving f2.length() in a variable y will only compute length() once, and in a for loop it will compute for every iteration, multiplying f2.length() computations n times for n number of iterations.

I am curious too. :)

Comment: We do not know how `File.length()` is implemented but there has to be some IO because the length of the file could change over time. And I/O that imply files are way more expensive than reading a variable

Comment: Of course ONLY if you can be sure that f2.length() doesn't have side effects / isn't impacted by what's happening in the loop - otherwise all `n` calls are needed.